# PDF Generation Salesforce

Tags: trigger, rest-api, cron, getcontent, getcontentaspdf

I'm kinda stuck in the middle of all the limitations Salesforce has for creating a pdf out of a Visualforce page.

What I have is a Visualforce page that takes some parameters and I use to rerender as a pdf using the getContent method inside an apex call.

The limitations I have:

- GetContent() can not be used inside: future method, trigger, cron job
- REST API: will cause a call out loop with the new critical update.
- Can not use restAPI inside cron jobs, or future methods, because I can not have a valid user session.

So my what I tried to do is to generate the pdf from a cron job and email it to a certain contact. Because of all the above limitations I'm kinda stuck.

Can you think of any other solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried emailing it as an attachment using a batch class? That could be run from a trigger if necessary.

Comment: You have explained the issue. Can you please explain little bit more on your requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's your timeline? Winter 16 will allow getcontent from @future:
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_pagereference_getcontent.htm

> You can now make calls to the getContent() and getContentAsPdf()
>   methods of the PageReference class from within asynchronous Apex such
>   as Batch Apex, Schedulable and Queueable classes, and @future methods.
>   This allows you to design much more flexible and scalable services
>   that, for example, render Visualforce pages as PDF files.
>
> Additionally, calls to getContent() and getContentAsPdf() that access
>   internal Salesforce URLs are treated as internal callouts, and
>   therefore not subject to callout limits.

Comment: Thanks, but one thing I noticed is that if they treat getContent() as an api call and if I'm using the REST api this will cause a api call loop.